# ASP.NET MVC - Model in Web project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, layer

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and inherited a project that uses the technology.

Such Web project contains three folders: `Views`, `Controllers` and `Model`. As I understand it, the Model contains in fact your domain / business logic and is called by your controllers. The controllers themselves act as delegators between Views and Model.

Now, in a typical layered architecture, there should be no references in any project to the Web/UI project.

I find this quite confusing:
-> The UI contains the Model, which is - in an ideal world - based on "Domain Driven Design"-principles.
-> The layers on top of the UI (Services and DataAccess) cannot have a reference to the UI

**How can you write efficient services and dataaccess layers if they do not know your model?**

What am I missing here? Is the Web.Model different from "DDD" and should I still have a separate BL project? If that is the case, then what is the Web.Model supposed to contain?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I view the Model as a concept. You can have a completely separate project containing your Domain (your entities, your services etc.) and reference that in your *"UI"* project. In this scenario this will be your *"Model"*.
This is what I typically do, In my Models folder I keep *"ViewModels"*, which I use for Binding/Validation (for the UI). 
For example, If I have an Employee but I don't necessary want to use all its properties (or for that matter different properties), I will create an `EmployeeViewModel` adjust it the way I want, I'll add validation (if required) and I'll pass it to my View.

This is by no means, "the right way"/"only way", but It worked for me in the past, and I thought I'll share (also, I'm pretty terrible in explanations, so I really hope this post makes sense, in case it doesn't or clarifications are needed - please let me know).

Answer (score 1):

You necessarily do not need to have your model in the same project. You can ofcourse have those in different layers.

This is how i usually setup my projects

**1) UI Project** - This is an MVC Web application type project where i will have my controllers and it's views and other UI related stuff

**2) Business Entities** - This will be a class library type project where i will define my domain objects ( Ex : Customer). This mostly looks similar to how my DB schema looks like. These are usually just POCO's which represent my domain modal ( I use this for the CodeFirst Database generation).

**3) Data Access** - This will be another class library type project which has the data access classes. Usually my repository class/interfaces, my DBContext class and other data access classes will be in this project.

**4) Tests** - Unit tests for the project

[image]

Business Entities project has been added as a reference to the Data Access Project so that i can use those classes in my Data access code.

Business Entities and Data Access Projects are added as references in UI Project. I would call the data access methods from my Controllers/ Service classes.

You may also add a Service/Business logic layer between your controller's and Data access layer as needed.

I have few ViewModel classes also inside my UI project ViewModels folder. I use this for some screens where i have to show data from multiple domain objects. I have a mapping/service class which maps the domain object to view model object. If your project is bifg, you may keep this as a serperate project under the same solution

Answer (score 0):

- Views Contain your HTML Layouts
- Controllers do the heavy lifting of getting data from the models or the models themselves and passing them to the Views.
- Models are used to do actions for your BL or fetch data.

Tip : You can use a EntityFramework ( i'm recommending it because it's easy to get started with ) to fetch your data and it's dead simple to setup thus eliminating your DAL and saving you time from writing everything yourself.

Services : you can have controllers that return XML/JSON (other format?) by converting the data you have got from the DB to XML/JSON and returning that instead of a view.
Take a look at MVC 4 WebApi for more details,Note that you can pretty much the same thing with mvc 3 too

Also refer to [asp.net/mvc](http://asp.net/mvc) site for tutorials to get you started, they are really useful.